# jQuery.ajax is not a function TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone see an issue with this minimal example below? I am including the latest version of jQuery in the header.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { //<--- works normally
    jQuery.ajax({ // <----- Error: "jQuery.ajax is not a function TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function"
        url: "test.html",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass("done");
    });
...
```

the error:

```
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery.ajax is not a function TypeError: jQuery.ajax is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (xxxx)
at l (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29567)
at c (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29869) undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You included jQuery slim in your project, it does not support jQuery.ajax. Use the full version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing functions in jQuery, make sure you are not the slim version  (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min). simply remove ".slim." and your expected functions will be present (jquery-3.3.1.min).